# How to loop li element with image using Jquery

Tags: jquery, json, loops, dynamic

How to loop li element with image using jquery from JSON data.

```
<ul id="slider">
     <li class="image photo1"><img src="images/photo01.jpg" alt="photo01"/></li>
     <li class="image photo2"><img src="images/photo02.jpg" alt="photo02"/></li>
</ul>
```

I need to display the images from DB using JSON. So the jQuery script should generate the li img element to load the images one by one using onClick function - Next and previous button. Thanks

Thanks

Comment: Can you add more details please?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Rendering the html will depend on the template engine but you could loop through the data as follows:

```
$.each(data, function(i, obj){
   //obj.id  obj.href   obj.alt
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

**all li with img** will be looped like below:

```
$( "#slider li" ).has( "img" ).each(data, function(i, obj){
  //all li with img tag
});
```